# Illustrator - 2 shapes, one able to nudge 0.01px the other only 1px

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 2 letters, both converted to outlines, one of them I can nudge 0.01px the other I can only nudge 1px but I can't figure out why!

Snap is off, smart guides are off and keyboard increment is set to 0.01px.

[image]

As you can see one is between 393 and 394, the other is dead on 395 :/

I have also tried copying the outlines in to a new file, saving that file then closing and reopening illustrator all together but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide a sample illustrator file?

Comment: @Paulo sure: http://www.iamsimon.co.uk/temp/test.ai

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your file, and nudging seems to be working correctly when I opened the file. However the file that I see might be different than the actual working file.
Here are a few things to investigate to try and resolve the problem.

- Is your artboard properly situated on whole pixels? ie: width and height are whole pixel values, the x and y positions are whole pixel values. If not, correct the position of your artboard(s)
- Have you tried to enter in values in the Transform palette rather than using nudge?
- Are your items ungrouped? or are you properly isolated on the correct element?
- Are you in Pixel Preview mode? You should be.
- Is your keyboard increment properly set to 1px in the General Preferences?

There could be any number of things that can cause the problem. Also, in the test file you provided, the shape isn't square and the shape itself didn't appear to be lined up on the pixel grid. Likely not the issue, but something that I noticed.

Comment: I see that you have the increment set to 0.01 pixels. It could also be that if you are in pixel preview mode, it don't really like that very much.